# Why does this two checks for null and empty returns different results?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Could anyone please explain how can I check if String is null or empty?

I have a below code which is giving different result explain why.

```
val someMap = ListMap[String,String]("key1" -> "")
val s = ""
println("s.isEmpty() : "+s.isEmpty())
println("someMap.get(\"key1\") : "+someMap.get("key1").toString().isEmpty)
```

Result is

```
s.isEmpty() : true
someMap.get("key1") : false
```

But why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because `Map.get` returns an [Option](http://blog.danielwellman.com/2008/03/using-scalas-op.html): either `Some(value)` if the value is in the Map or `None`, if there is no such key in Map.

If you turn `Some("")` to a string you'll get `"Some()"` which is definitely not empty.

To achieve the behavior you wanted, write your code as

```
someMap("key1").toString.isEmpty
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,Got it ans we can display the result by someMap.get("key1").get

Comment: @Azhar well, you can use `.get("key").get`, but it's a little quirky: you're not writting `1.toString.toInt`, right? That's quite the same.

Answer (score 2):

i assume the

```
val someMap = ListMap[String,String]("key1" -> "")
```

is a typo and you actually meant:

```
val someMap = Map[String,String]("key1" -> "")
```

The reason you get different results is that `get(key)` on maps returns `Option`. If given key is stored in a `Map`, calling `map.get(key)` returns `Some(<value_for_given_key>)`. If the given key is not stored in a `Map`, calling `map.get(key)` returns `None`.

In your example, you store value "" with key "key1" into `someMap`. Therefore, if you call `someMap.get("key1")`, you get `Some("")`. You then call `toString` on that value, which returns `"Some()"`. And `"Some()".isEmpty()` returns false for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the ListMap.get method you are calling returns an Option wrapped around your String:

```
def get(key: A): Option[B]
```

Try this improved println statement to see the actual result:

```
println("someMap.get(\"key1\") : "+someMap.get("key1"))
```

Using an IDE like Intellij's free Idea 12 CE can help you spot issues like this ahead of time by displaying the method's signature and providing code completion suggestions for its return value.

Answer (score 0):

I am checking null and empty with below code to avoid empty map error.

```
/**
 * isContain() will check is the key value is present in map or not and the value is null or Empty 
 * @Parameters : String
 * @return : Boolean
 */
def isContain(paramName : String,params : scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,String]) :  Boolean =
{
    if(!(params.contains(paramName)))
        return false
    !isNullOrEmpty(params(paramName))
}

/**
 * isNullOrEmpty() will check is the String null or Empty 
 * @Parameters : String
 * @return : Boolean
 */
def isNullOrEmpty(paramVal : String):  Boolean = {
      if(paramVal == null || paramVal.isEmpty())
          return true
      return false
}
```